# Ahoy is not storing events in the DB but there is a POST request in the logs

Tags: ahoy

I am having issues with getting Ahoy to register information to the database, but the logs are showing a post request:

```
Started POST "/ahoy/events" for 54.163.248.147 at 2015-08-05 22:43:41 +0000 Processing by Ahoy::EventsController#create as JSON Parameters: {"_json"=>[{"id"=>"34e8f9b6-a85f-4e15-a7f4-0992fd68cb71", "name"=>"$view", "properties"=>{"url"=>"http://unshakable-missile-106309.nitrousapp.com:3000/", "title"=>"Trendosaur", "page"=> "/"}, "time"=>1438814619.857}], "event"=>{}}
```

Any ideas why this isn't saving to the database?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright worked it out, for some reason in my initialiser it had:

```
class Ahoy::Store < Ahoy::Stores::LogStore
```

As opposed to:

```
class Ahoy::Store < Ahoy::Stores::ActiveRecordStore
```